# Upload file without form

Tags: php, javascript

**Upload file without form**
Yes i used the search button but i just couldn't find the solution i need.
Is there any way to upload a file so that user wouldn't need to press any form buttons?

My first idea was to use CURL but then i remembered that CURL is server sided.

I know it's possible thru Java and/or Flash but is there any way to do that using PHP & OR Javascript?

**Edit:
Thanks for clearing this for me but...**
*But what about PHP based FTP upload?**

Comment: I certainly hope not.  I don't want any application or web form uploading files from my computer without me clicking anything.

Comment: @Ardi You obviously cannot do it with PHP, since it is server-sided too. JavaSript can do it. Do you possibly use a JavaScript library? btw I am assuming that the  file is already selected via an INPUT type file field.

Comment: @Šime: if you're talking about ActiveX and consorts, that won't work crossbrowser and even then, it wouldn't work without warnings/confirmation dialogs.

Comment: Best you can achieve is auto submit the form once user selects a file. You can't and it must never be possible for client side script to auto-select file from the visitor file system!!

Comment: @Šime: that still require user interaction to select the file. The OP was asking for a way **without** any user interaction.

Comment: @BalucC The OP wants to **upload** the file without user interaction. He didn't say that the user does not select the file via an `<input type=file>` field.

Comment: @Šime: true, there's a little ambiguity, but the answer on that would have been *too* obvious :) Especially when considering the fact that the OP had the initial idea to leech the file from the client unaskingly with help of curl.

Comment: FTP will require even more user actions

Comment: So using flash might be the only workaround for that problem?

Comment: @Ardi: what about drag and drop? Is this acceptable? Meaning that instead of clicking `browse` and choosing file, user will be able to drag and drop the file.

Comment: @Shadow Drag and Drop using new HTML's feature? Well my goal is to upload a file without any user interaction.

Comment: @Ardi when posting comment use `@` like I'm doing here to notify people otherwise they won't see you commented..

Comment: @Ardi so I fear you're at dead end due to the reasons discussed already.

Comment: @Okay, thanks alot, i'm new here...and i haven't had time to discover such features of Stackoverflow jet.

Edit: It seems so...but i won't rest until i find a workaround ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't. That would have been a huge security hole. Your best bet is really an officially signed(!) Java applet. An unsigned or a manually signed one would still emit scary warnings to the enduser before proceeding.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply, but thanks for saying that, i feel really stupid for trying to do that with CURL.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution. Copy does not take local files and the example of submiting the file does not work if it is local. What you have to do is:

```
file_get_contents("file:///C:\img.jpg")
```

then write to a text file the contents in the server (for example */uploads/img.txt*) and rename to the same extension of the file to see the image.
It really works with any kind of file.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean without pressing any form buttons ?
well you could do a javascript `document.getElementById('FORM_NAME').submit();` if you want some function in javascript to do the upload , where `FORM_NAME` is the id or your current html form .

but you CAN NOT make your webpage select the file to upload , you have to let the user select the file in an `<input type="file">` element .

otherwise use a java applet

Comment: That still require that `<input type="file">` has a value. You can't prefill it in PHP/HTML nor fill it by JS.